# adding xml value to table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xslt

I have my xml file like this

```
<SamplingPlanProject>
   <CoordinateSystem>Lat/Long</CoordinateSystem>
   <InputUnits>M</InputUnits>
   <ProjectEngineerFirstName>Scott</ProjectEngineerFirstName>
   <ProjectEngineerLastName>Deaton</ProjectEngineerLastName>
   <ProjectName>1</ProjectName>
   <ProjectNumber>Test Project</ProjectNumber>
   <SamplingPlanProjectGUID>e91da635-0b5d-4e15-b71e-8e1986cf7a9d</SamplingPlanProjectGUID>
   <SamplingPlanProjectSite>
       <SiteID>Test Site</SiteID>
       <SamplingPlanProjectSiteGUID>42113b66-92b2-4387-b17b-3a346b980f3c</SamplingPlanProjectSiteGUID>
   </SamplingPlanProjectSite>
</SamplingPlanProject>
```

Now how to add these elements values to SQL Server table? I have separate table for `samplingplanprojectsite` which has the columns `siteid`, `SamplingPlanProjectSiteGUID` and `SamplingPlanProjectGUID`

Can anyone help out form this?

How to write code for this to get values to `rows`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddEmp
    @empXml xml
AS

INSERT INTO Employee
(
    siteID,
    samplingPlanProjectSiteGUID,
    samplingPlanProjectGUID
)
VALUES
(
    @empXml.value('(/SamplingPlanProject/CoordinateSystem/InputUnits/SiteID)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
   @empXml.value('(/SamplingPlanProject/CoordinateSystem/InputUnits/SamplingPlanProjectSiteGUID)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
   @empXml.value('(/SamplingPlanProject/CoordinateSystem/InputUnits/SamplingPlanProjectGUID)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
)
```

NOTE:- I have considered the name of the table as EMP and table column name as above. Do change the values as per your reqirement.